# How to automatically change dynamic action's condition on several pages?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

We've got an Oracle APEX application with dozens of pages that are automatically created using the PL/SQL API. Each of these pages contains several dynamic actions (created with `wwv_flow_api.create_page_da_event`), and we now need to change one of these from

```
Identification
  Sequence: 100

When
  Event: IR Freeze Header - Start 
  Selection Type: Region
  Region: (30)
  Condition: - No condition -
```

to

```
Identification
  Sequence: 45

When
  Event: IR Freeze Columns - Start
  Selection Type: Region
  Region: (30)
  Condition: - No condition -
```

on every page. I don't want to do this manually on 50+ pages, so I'm looking for a way to automatically do this.

My initial guess was something like `wwv_flow_api.change_page_da_event`, but unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exist an API function that allows me to change an existing dynamic action.

The only solution I found so far is to directly update the `APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_DA` table:

```
update APEX_040200.apex_application_page_da
set 
  when_Event_internal_name = 'PLUGIN_COM.AF.PLUGIN.JQ.IRFREEZECOLS|DYNAMIC ACTION|start',
  dynamic_action_sequence = 45 
where application_Id = 175
and dynamic_action_name = 'setColumnWidth';
```

but I don't want to do this, since it might void our APEX support.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Just another tack, I don't know the nature of the plugin you're using, but if I had 50+ pages with lots of similar-type dynamic actions, I'd look into writing a single javascript/jquery function to do the work, instead of creating 50+ dynamic actions. But of course I don't know your specific circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wwv_flow_api package is not really designed for modifying an existing Apex application - that's what the GUI builder is for. It's not [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/toc.htm), for that matter (although there are [hints](http://michaelhichwa.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/apex-423-released-new-packaged-app-data.html) that there may be a documented package in Apex 5.0).

The approach I'd try in your case is to export the application to a SQL file, edit that file (carefully!), then try re-importing it.

Comment: Exporting + re-importing would probably work, but I'd like to avoid that if possible - I've had some issues with that approach in the past (broken non-ASCII characters, for example).

Comment: Perhaps try again, maybe the issues you had "in the past" are now resolved. And I'd be worried if export/import isn't working - that's a minimum requirement in any environment I work in.